# get text from web page as String

Tags: java, android, http

I've got my own implementation of this wrapped up in a function that takes a URL argument but I can't help thinking there must be a nice function that does this already within the Android API.

Does such a function exist?

**EDIT: Oops. I would just like the text - not the HTML.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you're pulling the content via http, you're going to have to parse out the HTML elements.  The only way around this would be if you're calling a script that will return data in other formats based on a query string, which doesn't sound like what you're asking.

If you'd like a good example of how to parse out the HTML, check out the Wiktionary sample on http://d.android.com, specifically the files:

- [SimpleWikiHelper.java](http://d.android.com/resources/samples/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/SimpleWikiHelper.html) which
  pulls the page contents from the
  stream
- [ExtendedWikiHelper.java](http://d.android.com/resources/samples/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/ExtendedWikiHelper.html)
  which parses out the HTML (using
  RegEx) into content used in the
  application.

I doubt that fully answers your question, but I hope it steers you in the right direction.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't "get" what he was looking for, but you did... +1, good sir.

Comment: Also, ran across an HTML helper: `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)`  Although, it doesn't support all HTML tags, and the reference is somewhat lacking.